# Add the evens and odds to get the entire space.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions

Consider the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of functions $f$ from $(-1, 1)$ to the reals such that $f(x)$ is differentiable infinitely many times at every $x$ in $(-1, 1)$. Let me call this vector space $V$. And consider the following subspaces of this $E$, which are the even functions in $V$, and $O$, the odd functions in $V$.

Why is it that $V$ is equal to the direct sum of $V$ and $O$? How does one "visualize" a rigorous proof of this from first principles? What is the intuition behind this, hopefully geometric?

Comment: Don't you mean V is sum of E and O (not V and O).

Comment: Hint, Think about $e(x) = f(x) + f(-x)$ and $o(x) = f(x)-f(-x)$. If you graph those for some relatively random $f$ you might see the intuition.

Comment: To show $V = E \oplus O$, you need to show two things. The first is that $E \cap O = \{0\}$, i.e. the only function which is both even and odd is zero. The second is that $V = E + O$, i.e. every function can be written as a sum $e + o$ for some $e \in E$ and $o \in O$.

Answer (score 1):

Every $f \in V$ is the sum of an even and an odd function, namely $(f(x)+f(-x))/2$ and $(f(x) - f(-x))/2$.  Moreover, these are the only even and odd functions whose sum is $f$.